# await/async causing "Access Denied" in remote WMI

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, wmi

I am retrieving a service list via WMI on a Win Server 2008 R2 machine that I have administrative access (and am accessing with a specific admin account). I think the security is ok because I'm able to pull back the data both in .net and in wbemtest.

The problem comes when I take the exact same code and use await and async to access the data. At that point I get an "Access denied" when I use a foreach to iterate through the returned object.

I'd like to stress that it returns the ManagementObjectCollection just fine. It also works fine if I don't use await.  The only difference between working and not working is the async keyword on the method and the addition of the await code, as showing below:

```
ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = await Task.Run(() => Operations.ConnectService(wmipath, username, password));
```

The Operations.ConnectService is a static method that actually gets the collection just fine.  The problem I'm having is this: why am I getting "Access denied" when I go from blocking to threaded?  What am I missing?

Comment: The code snippet is out of the context, so it's hard to tell what happens. However, I suspect this is something to do with the current identity on a thread. Try to find differences in the debugger in System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() in the code that performs the query "Operations.ConnectService(...)" and in the code that runs after "await".

Comment: Thanks, I'll start poking around in that direction.

Comment: If you find that your code runs under different users, you might want to do this: `var ctx = System.Security.SecurityContext.Capture(); System.Security.SecurityContext.Run(ctx, () => { ... }, null);`